# Persistent scripts with Node.js?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

I'm not sure if this is a setting somewhere that I've missed or an actual issue with Node.js.

Anyhow, my problem is that I want to run a script that handles web socket connections. I can get the script running as a service and it handles the connections as it should. After being idle for a while (ie. not receiving or sending any data; I'm still connected from the client, but I'm doing something else, like checking my gmail for a while in another window) the script shuts down. It does respawn as it should since I told it to in my .conf, but that doesn't matter since the clients already have been disconnected.

So the question is this: *is there a way to make sure that the script keeps running even when the clients are idle?* Maybe it's a setting on the ubuntu server?

**Tech**:

Running on a Ubuntu Server 10.04 on Slicehost

I'm using Node v0.5.0-pre and the websocket-server module

Comment: 0.5 is unstable. I recommend you use 0.4.8. What is a .conf file? You should just run a websocket server and it should stay running.

Comment: Ah. Look at that. :) Seems like I got 0.5 when I followed different "install like this"-guides. Never gave it much thought. This might have done the trick.

Comment: Oh, and a .conf is a file in /etc/init in Ubuntu which defines how Upstart services should be executed, if that makes any sense? It basically says "run the server script when the system starts and restart it if it chrashes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[socket.setTimeout(0)](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/net.html#socket.setTimeout) ?

Comment: This and making sure that I ran version 0.4.8 of Node seems like a waterproof way of keeping it running, indeed.